# An algorithm for merging matched lines?

Tags: merge, matching, lines

I've designed an algorithm that matches correspondent lines seen from different positions of a robot.

Now I want to merge correspondent lines into one.

Does anyone know an algorithm for this purpose?

Comment: Is the algorithm you designed purely in pseudocode?  If it's in an actual language, please post the code.

Comment: it's in c++, but it's too long to be posted here.
what I'm interested in is the procedure. language is a detail

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, which mentions you should "include enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem".  i.e. please give us an excerpt of your code.

Comment: anyway, each line is represented by its extremes, a point on it, its normal, its slope and distance from origin

Comment: What do you mean by merge into one? Do you want to take the information from these lines to estimate the view from a different place (a virtual camera)? Do you want to estimate their 3D positioning? Do you want to mosaic the images like panoramic photos are sometimes composed from separate pictures? Please elaborate.

Comment: I'm working in 2D. I extracted lines from 2 laser scan and they lie on a plan.
then, I performed the matching: I know that a line A in scan 1 corresponds to line B seen by robot in scan 2.
professor has asked me to merge each couple of line into just one line and I have doubts about which is the best way of doing this.
I thought that i could simply keep one of the lines in the couple and drop the other and add to my list of lines the ones in scan 2 that are not visible in scan 1.
by applying this tactic many times, considering new scans after #2,  this should allow reconstruction of map

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you're trying to do is a mosaic but restricted to 2D. Or at least something similar considering only extracted features. I'll go through the basic idea of how to do it (as I remember it anyway).

1. You extract useful features in both images (your lines)
2. You do feature matching (your matching)
3. You extract relative positional information about your cameras from the matched features. This allows to determining a transform between the two.
4. You transform one image into the other's perspective or both to a different perspective

Since you say you're working in a 2D plane that's where you will want to transform to. If your scans can be considered to not add any 3D distortion (always from the same hight facing perpendicular to the plane) then you need only deal with 2D transformations.

To do what you call the merging of the lines you need to perform step 3 and 4 of the mosaic algorithm.

For step 3 you will need to use a robust approach to calculate your 2D Transformation (rotation and translation) from one picture/scan to the other. Probably something like least mean squares (or other approaches for estimating parameters from multiple values).

For step 4 you use the calculated 2D transform and possibly a previous transformation that was calculated for the previous picture (not needed if you're matching from the composed image, a.k.a moasic, to a new image instead of sequetial images) use it on the image it would apply to. In your case probably just your 2D lines from the new scan (and not a full image) will need to be transformed by this global 2D transform to take their position and orientation to the global map reference.

Hope this helps. Good Luck!

Comment: thanks for help.
actually, I've already gone through all the steps you listed. so, given 2 subsequent scans, I've computed the transformations matrix T to move map lines from one scan to another. then, once lines from both scan were in the same reference frame, I've ran my matching algortihm and computed pairs of matched lines. my final goal is progressively reconstruct the portion of environment seen by robot along its path. suppose M is the portion of the map already reconstructed and S is a new scan not analyzes yet. I:
- extract lines in S
...

Comment: ...
- use a least square approach to extrimate a transformation matrix T from S to M
- use T transform lines from S to M
- match correspondent lines
- merge each couple of corrspondent lines into one
- add unmatched lines S as new lines in the map

my doubt are about the right modality to perform penultimare step.
I imagined that I could simply ignores lines in S that found a match in M and simply add unmatched lines to my portion of map non reconstructed so far. anyway, i'm not pretty sure of this. maybe there's a way to merge lines from a matched couple into a brand new line

Comment: I imagine a line is a set of parameters so using the least squares on all matched lines so far to update map line would be a way to go that needs all lines to be preserved to update the "merged lines" once more matches where found. Another way that requires less memory is averaging the line parameters weighed by the number of lines already merged. Since matched lines are already considered close enough to current representation the average averaging should not be likely to cause bad results (like the ones of averaging big positive and big negative numbers and getting 0)

Comment: thanks for your contribution. would you explain better how you'd use a LS approach by exploiting line's representation?
once a merged line is obtained, how can I be sure that all merged lines are still connected each others by one extreme and they don't overlap?

Comment: I haven't really used this approach for this purpose. I have really only done photo mosaic. But I guess if you're interested in connections between lines (more precisely line segments) you need to keep track of corners where the line segments are joined and treat several line segments as the features matched (not just one line segment at a time) that way lines from both sides of a corner will count to determine that corner position and then the 'merged lines' will still be connected since your representation has the corner as one single parameter belonging to both lines instead of  one each.

Comment: each segment is represented by a 10x1 vector, including: the coordinates of middlepoint, the components of normal, segment's slope, segment's distance from origin, coordinates of segment's extremes.
how would you act?

Comment: Sorry, no real advise to give. All the knowledge I have is from some modules from over 6 years ago. I'm sure a simple approach of just adding lines to the map that aren't there yet will give you a good enough result for most cases. Good Luck!